# What happened to origin after creating a new Git branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

When I create a branch using `git branch clean_up`, a new branch clean_up is created. Now when I execute `git branch` command, I see two branches clean_up and master, what happened to origin?

Comment: origin is a remote, not a branch. Try `git remote`

Answer (score 2):

Origin is (default) name of remote repository. You can show them using `git remote -v`

Answer (score 1):

Try `git branch -a` to list both remote-tracking branches and local branches